# pass arguements to function called in addEventListener

Tags: javascript

If I am calling a function in addEventListener like this:

```
document.querySelector('.elem').addEventListener('click', expand);
```

The expand function takes arguments. How can I pass those arguments to it?

I've tried

```
document.querySelector('.elem').addEventListener('click', expand(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an anonymous function call

```
document.querySelector('.elem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    expand(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}, false);
```

if you need the value of `this` to be the element, you could use `bind`, `apply` or `call`

```
document.querySelector('.elem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    expand.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second one was exactly what I needed!